# mediaPlayer.stop isn't stopping

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to one button was responsible for playing and pausing music. I also want to change the button background depend on its state. 
When I click "play" music start playing and the background image is changing to "pause". 
When I click "pause" music don't stop playing but the background image is changing again to "play"

I checked if it works when I set mediaPlayer.stop() to the other button(not to the same) and it works.

```
public boolean isplaying=false;
public void onClick(View view)
{
    int clickedViewId = view.getId();
    switch(clickedViewId){
        case R.id.time_playButton:
            {
                playpauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_playButton);
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.time);

                if(isplaying==false){
                    start();
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    stop();
                    return;
                }

            }
        case R.id.time_ytButton:
            //if I write here
            //mediaPlayer.stop() 
            // it working well but this button is for other thing
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwYX52BP2Sk")));
    }
}

public void start(){
    playpauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    isplaying=true;
}
public void stop(){
    playpauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    Toast.makeText(songs.this, "Checking if mediaPlayer.stop() is calliing on and it is but don't know why isn't work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    isplaying=false;
}
```

Comment: Every time you click `time_playButton`, you're creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer` and assigning it to `mediaPlayer`, so you're calling `stop()` on the wrong instance.

Comment: "I checked if it works when I set mediaPlayer.stop() to the other button(not to the same) and it works." - Yes, because you're not assigning a new instance of `MediaPlayer` to the `mediaPlayer` variable when you click the other `Button`

Comment: how can I write it that I don't creating a new instance of MediaPlayer in onClick method ? when I write it before onClick method I get error "uknown error"